# EmberJS - Checkboxes and Getting Values in Controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, checkbox

Below is a simple example how I intend to use check boxes. What I have is an array of terms with `id` and `name` field and each post can be assigned to a single or multiple terms/categories.

```
var config = {};

config.terms = [
    {id: 1, termName: 'Red'},
    {id: 2, termName: 'Green'},
    {id: 3, termName: 'Blue'}
];
```

### Problem

With EmberJS handlebar expression I am showing those checkboxes but I am confused what to use as form element variable `name` field doesn't seem to defined in the controller. The `checked` field works as controller property but when I add `termName` as checked all of the checkboxes are checked by default and label after checking changes after clicking checkboxes.

**What I need to get on the controller is the term names that are selected**

Below is the example code. You can also find it on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sisir/kqxz71sg/1/). Check uncheck the red/green/blue checkboxes to see the problem. Also have a look in console.

### HTML

```
<div id="main"></div>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    {{#each term in terms}}
        {{input type="checkbox" name=term.name}} {{term.name}}
    {{/each}}
    <button {{action "submit"}}>Submit</button>
</script>
```

### JS

```
var config = {};

config.terms = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Red'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Green'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Blue'}
];

App = Ember.Application.create({
    rootElement: '#main'
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller){
        controller.set('terms', config.terms);
    }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        submit: function(){
            console.log(this.Red);
            console.log(this.Blue);
            console.log(this.Green);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you jsfiddle example you'r binding the name to the checked value of the checkbox. I think that's not what you want to do.

The checked value should be bound to a boolean value.

So,

**1st approach: either add a property to your term object (selected: false)**

```
 config.terms = [
     {id: 1, name: 'Red', selected: false },
     {id: 2, name: 'Green', selected: false },
     {id: 3, name: 'Blue', selected: false }
 ];
```

(as Ember objects:)

```
 config.terms = [
     Em.Object.create({id: 1, name: 'Red', selected: false }),
     Em.Object.create({id: 2, name: 'Green', selected: false }),
     Em.Object.create({id: 3, name: 'Blue', selected: false })
 ];
```

and then bind the property in your template this way:

```
{{input type="checkbox" checked=term.selected}}
```

**2nd approach: bind it to controller properties:**

```
// inside your controller:
redSelected: false,
greenSelected: false,
blueSelected: false,


{{input type="checkbox" checked=controlller.redSelected}}
```

Comment: Okey understood. But thing is the red, green or blue terms are arbitrary. It could be any numbers of terms with any name. Think this as categories of a blog post.

Comment: Then use the first approach I mentioned. Add a property to you term objects. I've updated my answer.